# How can I ask user l'L'l for his simple Quicktime Playlist player?

Tags: discussion

How can I contact a user of this site?

I think the user name is l'L'l and he had offered it somewhere but I dont know how to ask him for software that plays Quicktime movies like mplayer -playlist (yourplaylist) or realplayer bla.ram. Series of URLs in ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

If you earn more reputation you can participate in the chat forums. If you earn even more reputation, you can write comments on others' posts.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your contact information in your profile (the info I edited out of your question body). Similarly, if someone wants to be contacted outside the site, you can look in their profile.

If you link to the user in question, I'll explain where that contact info lies. For me, look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike

The site notification methods are to @user ping them in comments or chat. Both of these require you to gain some reputation so asking here is your only hope of pinging the user without them self-disclosing their contact information or you gaining reputation.

Answer (score 0):

However in general you can't contact an individual user. This is by design in Stack Exchange see [this meta stackexchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)